# Team Members not showing in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to switch to Visual Studio 2013 from 2010.

One feature I use in VS2010 is the Team Members list from the Team Explorer pane. That feature is not included in Visual Studio, but is included in Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools, which I have installed.

Now I have installed VS2013, and also Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools, but I don't see the Team Members list anywhere in VS2013.

How can I get the Team Members list to show up in VS2013?

Here is what my Team Explorer pane looks like in VS 2013 and VS 2010 for me:
[image: Team explorer 2013 vs 2010]

Comment: Are there any team members?

Comment: Yes, I can see them all in VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case somebody still comes to this question, the problem probably is that your TFS version is 2010.

Comment: Do you mean the TFS server is still 2010 or a client installed on your computer?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously that functionality *should* be default but unfortunately isn't.

Luckily you can add it with the [**Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f?SRC=VSIDE) free add-in.

Comment: I **do** have the TFS 2013 power tools installed, but there is still no team members button. It says so right there in my question, you must not have read all of it: *Now I have installed VS2013, and also Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools, but I don't see the Team Members list anywhere in VS2013.*

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice that you had the power tools too. A colleague had been complaining of the same issue but turned out he didn't have the power tools.

Comment: Do you have the "TFS Team Collaboration" extension listed in VS? This should have been installed as part of the power tools but may be disabled?

Comment: This did actually work for me. After installing power tools Team Members was displayed

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are one of the team members in that specific project, security options are not enough.

Comment: I am one of the team members in that specific project. Could you post a screenshot of how it looks on your computer?

Comment: I've also added a screenshot of how my team explorer window looks. I don't have a "team members" button.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this:
To get Team Members to show in 2013, you need to have Members in the Web Team (which is separate from normal Source Control Security Settings).
We add our Project Contributors to our Web Team to give them access to the Team Members functionality.